# C# Outlook Interop Send from Folder

Tags: c#, outlook, sendmail

I'm attempting to send an email from a e-mail address that's listed as a folder. Basically I have a folder with an e-mail address assigned to it. Whenever something comes to that email it goes to the folder. The E-Mail Address is not an account assigned to me. I would use SMTP But our corporate network does not allow this.

How can I send an e-mail in C# from this Folder's E-Mail?

My code is setup as follows.

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.Subject = subject;

string html;
html = message;

html = html.Replace("\n","<br/>");
oMsg.HTMLBody = html;
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(to);


//Rest of my closing stuff here.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the folder's email address (you don't mention if this is part of the problem but it sounds like it is not) you shouldn't have to use Outlook interop for this. Try the classes in `System.Net.Mail`. [This site](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) has some good examples, but here's something quick:

```
const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
...

var msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString());
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(folderAddress));
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = html;

var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("{SMTP server address or IP}");
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

I'm only guessing about the part where I get the recipient address, it's based on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184647.aspx).

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention. Our networks do not allow us to use the corporate SMTP Server. I have to sent/receive mail through outlook only.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the whole folder thingy is irrelevant to your problem (correct me if I'm wrong there), and all it comes down to is you want to send an e-mail through Outlook with a specific reply address. You can use [MailItem.SenderEmailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175525%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for that purpose:

```
oMsg.SenderEmailAddress = "my.special.address@domain.com"
```

As an alternative, you could add the reply address to the [MailItem.ReplyRecipients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175522%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection.

Comment: Both of these objects are set as read only. I believe they are for if statements as opposed to actually setting the values of the email being sent.

I feel like i'm missing something with these objects, but I cant find anything to the contrary.